# Updates to an uncommitted Perforce changelist in a code collaborator peer review

Tags: perforce, code-collaborator

I have created a Code Collaborator peer review from an uncommitted Perforce changelist. This works fine, and the peer review is going swimmingly. A defect was found, and the changes were made. Now, I want the peer review updated with the new version of the file.

When I try to upload the new version of the file, it adds it as a new resource rather than a new version of the existing file already in the peer review. When I try to upload the entire uncommitted changelist again, it shows up as a new version of that same uncommitted changelist. In other words, I can't seem to get the existing file in the peer review to show up with my changes...everything I do adds another resource in some form or fashion.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heard from CodeCollaborater on this. Apparently the way to approach this is to consistently upload the entire pending changelist when you want any updates to show up in the peer review. This will still show multiple sets of the peer review files (one set for reach time the pending changelist is uploaded).

You can, however, change the view of the Review Summary screen to "compact" all those sets into one. Each reviewer wanting to see this presentation needs to select the following in the Review Materials section of the review:

> View as: Overlay